# I'm Canadian.  Do I need to pay tax twice on my U.K.-based savings or claim as income?

Tags: canada, income-tax, united-kingdom

I am a Canadian citizen and have money in an account for a friend in the United Kingdom.  I have been taxed on this portion. My question is: will I be taxed when money is wired to my bank account in Canada?  Will I need to claim this money or will he when it is transferred to his account once opened here?

Answer (score 1):

In the general case if you have income coming in from a foreign source you need to declare it on your Canadian tax form, and nominally pay tax on it. However Canada has a tax agreement with the UK to ensure that you are not taxed twice. You also declare how much tax you have paid to the UK, and that is deducted from your Canadian tax bill. You may need to consult a tax professional, or maybe just read the Revenue Canada website to get the details.

If you are holding this money for a friend, then you may find that this does not count as income to you. If you are getting it transferred to you in Canada, and then immediately passed on to your friend, it probably doesn't count as income (though again a tax professional will probably be helpful). This would mean you don't have to pay Canadian tax. But it's also a bummer because you've paid UK tax, which you might also have avoided, and you can't get that back without a lot of form filling.

If this is going to be an ongoing situation, and the amount is significant, then you might look at getting your friend's money (and any you have in a UK account yourself) transferred to an offshore account, where UK tax is not automatically deducted. Most UK banks will do this for non-UK residents.